# passing variable from php page to java applet

Tags: java, php

I am trying to pass variable from php to java applet. This is the code at php side.
The session variable is not empty and contains the email address I checked it.

```
$email=$_SESSION['Email'];
<applet code='mainapplet' archive="applet.jar" width="600" height="400">
<param name="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" />
</applet>
```

In the applet I have this code inside the applet init method

```
email=this.getParameter("email");
```

but the string variable email is always returning null. Where am I wrong
This is the HTML generated code

```
<applet code='mainapplet' archive="applet.jar" width="600" height="400">
<param name="email" value="sangwan.ritesh@yahoo.in" />
</applet>
```

Comment: Is the email showing up in your generated HTML?

Comment: Are you sure this doesn't throw a syntax error? The third line looks broken to me.

Comment: @andrewsi yes the email is shown in generated html

Comment: @TillHelge no syntax error the code is running fine

Answer (score 0):

```
<param name="email" value="<?php echo $email;"/>
```

Should be..

```
<param name="email" value="<?php echo $email;?>"/>
```

Comment: yeah i closed the php tag in my page it's typing mistake here

Comment: I mean the email is still not being passed even though I closed php tag in my code it's typing mistake here but I do closed the tag in the actual page

Answer (score 0):

You dont have closing PHP tag:

```
<param name="email" value="<?php echo $email;?>"/>
```

Comment: That is still wrong, the double quote inside the PHP tag would throw a Syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot your PHP closing tag.

```
<?php echo $email;?>
```